# Configure apache with digest SHA1 encryption algorithm

Tags: apache, iis, wamp

We are trying to setup apache(version 2.2) with digest authentication using SHA1 encryption algorithm.But when we change "httpd.conf" file using "AuthDigestAlgorithm SHA1", apache doesn't get started after this.
Its shows error in below syntax

> "AuthDigestAlgorithm SHA1"

Please help how can I set up apache with digest-sha1 algorithm.

Comment: [Check the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html) looks like the only option is MD5|MD5-sess and MD5-sess is not correctly implemented in 2.2 or 2.4

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But we need to implement for SHA-1 only so please suggest how can we implement that??

Comment: I will also keep an eye open on this.